# Tableview won't reload data after selecting row

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, uisearchcontroller

When I select any row in tableView data should be removed. I have set selected text in textField which is working, but tableView data is not cleared after selection, code given below.

Please help me.

[image]

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    [self.tblViewSearch deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];

    TimeZoneCity *objCity = (TimeZoneCity *)[searchResult objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    txtfieldTimeZone.text=objCity.timezone;
    [searchResult removeAllObjects];
    [self.tblViewSearch reloadData];
}
```

Comment: your question is not properly formatted also share some code what you have done

Comment: you should hide tableview on cell select

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to remove the table view you could try this. This is a bad idea if you have set up your table view with interface builder, since it does the creation for you in this case.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    [self.tblViewSearch deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
    TimeZoneCity *objCity = (TimeZoneCity *)[searchResult objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    txtfieldTimeZone.text=objCity.timezone;
    [self.tblViewSearch removeFromSuperview];
}
```

A better strategy might be to just hide it, and then show it again when needed. To make it look nicer you could add an animation too.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    [self.tblViewSearch deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
    TimeZoneCity *objCity = (TimeZoneCity *)[searchResult objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    txtfieldTimeZone.text=objCity.timezone;

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{
        self.tblViewSearch.alpha = 0.0;
    }];
}
```

Comment: nice answer it should be hidden tableview on cell click